# Strange Javascript/cross site cookies problem

Tags: javascript, cookies

I've got a PHP script running on domain B that, when called generates some JS.

The idea is that in a given html page I can have:

```
<script src="http://b.domain/myscript.php"></script>
```

So when the page loads, the script is called and the JS is generated and run on the local page.

The problem is that myscript.php depends on B's domain cookies. If I type http://b.domain/myscript.php into my address bar, the script works fine, and I see the JS text in the browser window.

But when I include the quoted line above in a webpage running on a different webserver, call it A, it doesnt work. The JS is still generated, but is incorrect, as none of the cookies are available to the script.

So, in short, access the script directly, cookies are available, all is well.
Access the script via a call from a page served from another domain and it doesnt have access to the cookies.

I dont understand why, in a call to a script running on the B domain, the browser doesnt seem to be sending B's cookies?

Comment: Providing the OS and browser versions would likely help in getting an answer.  Or does this happen in all browsers?

Comment: Browser is Firefox (latest version), domain A is apache on my local machine (WinXP), domain B is apache on a Redhat linux box. A quick check with firebug shows that B's cookies arent being included in the call to myscript.php

Answer (score 1):

This is a security feature. Cookie information is never made available to a domain other than the one that set the cookie. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting  for more info.

Comment: But the script that runs on B only needs B's cookies. No cookies are required to be sent to any domain other than that which set them.

Comment: It doesn't matter which server the _script_ came from; the script can only operate with cookies from the domain the _page_ came from. Otherwise I could, for example, include a script hosted at Google Code on my site and, when you visited that page, my site could use the script to steal your Google cookie, giving me access to your GMail account.

Comment: The script doesnt use cookies - only the serverside script that generates the client side JS to run on the original page.